# Using "this" inside of a method (not for calling a method or constructor or variable)

Tags: java, vector, this

I tried to change the capacity of a vector without the use of the constructor parameter in the `Vector` class. So I created a `MyVector` class and extended it from `Vector`. Everything is working in this code but I couldn't understand using "this" in the `setCapacityIncrement(int capacityIncrement)` method.

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        MyVector<Integer> v = new MyVector<>(4);

        System.out.printf("Capacity=%d%n", v.capacity());

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
            v.add(i);

        System.out.printf("Capacity=%d%n", v.capacity());

        v.setCapacityIncrement(10);

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
            v.add(i);

        System.out.printf("Capacity=%d%n", v.capacity());
    }
}
```

MyVector class :

```
class MyVector<T> extends Vector<T> {
    public MyVector()
    {
        super();
    }

    public MyVector(int capacity)
    {
        super(capacity);
    }

    public MyVector(Collection<? extends T> coll)
    {
        super(coll);        
    }

    public MyVector(int capacity, int capacityIncrement)
    {
        super(capacity, capacityIncrement);
    }

    public void setCapacityIncrement(int capacityIncrement)
    {
        this.capacityIncrement = capacityIncrement;
    }
}
```

Comment: ı konw that but when i add "int capacityIncrement ;" in MyVector class its give me different result.

Comment: What do you mean, when you add "int capacityIncrement;"?

Comment: class MyVector<T> extends Vector<T> { int capacityIncrement ;
public MyVector()
{
    super();
}

Comment: You don't want to do that because `capacityIncrement` is already a protected field on `Vector` which you are extending. If you added it as a field to your own class then you would be hiding the field in the `Vector` class.

Comment: so u say that Vector is already have a field like int capacityIncrement.. now everthing is make sense. ı couldt understand becouse ı dont know the code of Vector class. did ı understand u right ?

Comment: Yes you understood correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `this.capacityIncrement` because the field is shadowed by the parameter capacityIncrement since they have the same name.

If you did `capacityIncrement  = capacityIncrement;` you would be assigning the same value to your capacityIncrement parameter which would have no effect.

If they did not have the same name then `this` would not be required as in below:

```
public void setCapacityIncrement(int increment)
{
    capacityIncrement = increment;
}
```

Based on your edit it would also be a bad idea to have a `capacityIncrement` field in your `MyVector` class because there is already a protected variable with the same name in the parent `Vector`.

That would cause the `Vector capacityIncrement` field to be shadowed by your own.

Answer (score 0):

when you use "this" you are referring to the object of the class.
Therefore, this.capacityIncrement refers to the variable capacityIncrement in the object of the vector class tat its called from. Notice that the parameter passed into the method is also called capacityIncrement. So if you just wrote,
capacityIncrement = capacityIncrement without the "this." the compiler would just assume you're referring to the local variable i.e. the parameter.

The variable capacityIncrement is a protected variable in the vector class. this means that only the vector class or classes extending the vector class can access it directly.